# Get value of OTP one time code in moblie browser JS

Tags: javascript, one-time-password, mobile-browser

**Testing on iPhone, iOS 16. Chrome & Firefox browsers.**

I'm creating a page with one time password form, which consists of 6 inputs. When user is on this page, he/she will get a SMS with OTP code. I would like to auto fill those inputs once SMS is received, so user is not bothered **(in Mobile version of course)**.

My question is - is there way to get/read the code from SMS when its received? Is there an event that I can listen to, to read it? If not, what can be another solution here?

**What I've tried**

1. [WebOTAPI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebOTP_API) - TBH I don't get does it work. I've tried this, but seems like its never been triggered. `OTPCredential` object exists in `Window` but nothing happens.

   ```
   if ('OTPCredential' in window) {
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      const input = document.querySelector('input[autocomplete="one-time-code"]') as HTMLInputElement;
      if (!input) return;
      const ac = new AbortController();

      navigator.credentials
        .get({
          otp: { transport: ['sms'] },
          signal: ac.signal,
        })
        .then((otp: any) => {
          console.log(otp));
          input.value = otp.code;  // <-- never got here (-_-)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    });
   ```

   }
2. I've tried different inputs like

   ```
   <input id="single-factor-code-text-field" autocomplete="one-time-code" />

   <input type="text" inputmode="numeric" autocomplete="one-time-code" pattern="\d{6}" required />

   <!-- also like this -->
   <input type="text" name="token[0]" inputmode="decimal" id="token[0]" maxlength="6" autocomplete="one-time-code">
   <input type="text" name="token[1]" inputmode="decimal" id="token[1]" maxlength="6" autocomplete="one-time-code">
   <input type="text" name="token[2]" inputmode="decimal" id="token[2]" maxlength="6" autocomplete="one-time-code">
   <input type="text" name="token[3]" inputmode="decimal" id="token[3]" maxlength="6" autocomplete="one-time-code">
   <input type="text" name="token[4]" inputmode="decimal" id="token[4]" maxlength="6" autocomplete="one-time-code">
   <input type="text" name="token[5]" inputmode="decimal" id="token[5]" maxlength="6" autocomplete="one-time-code">
   ```

Such inputs only get filled if user clicks on input and then clicks on code hint. As I mentioned, I would like to auto fill the code.

[image]

3. I've tried [ClipboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent) but it also never triggers.

How this can be solved? Ideally listening to the event which has OTP code would be perfect (then I can easily auto fill inputs). Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It would be a security risk if having your web page open would suffice to snag codes received via SMS without user interaction (what if you were trying to impersonate the user on a bank website by doing that, and the SMS received comes from the bank and not you?) so I doubt that will work. It will be possible only in an app, I presume.

Comment: @CherryDT good point. I remember I used to do it, but as you said maybe it only worked in the app.

Comment: Are you including the domain and the code in the last line of the SMS like this: `@example.com #123456`? https://web.dev/sms-otp-form/#format

Comment: @hectorct yes I do